# Scrollbars on canvas in tkinter does not work

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, scroll

Yes there are many stackoverflow questions regarding this, i saw everything but could not get this working so i am asking a new question with my code:

Basically i want to create a table in tkinter with 4 columns. But i want to be able to scroll this because the rows will be later taken from the mysql database. but i cannot get the scroll working.

Here is my code :

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x600")

frame_canvas = Frame(root)
frame_canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

canvas = Canvas(frame_canvas)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

vsb = Scrollbar(frame_canvas, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

for i in range(0, 50):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        canvas.columnconfigure(j, minsize=150)
        Label(canvas, text="hello"+str(i)+str(j)).grid(row=i, column=j)

canvas.config(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

app = root
root.mainloop()
```

How to i get the canvas to scroll ? Is there another way to create a table ? Also later if i want to add a row to the bottom of the table, how is it possible ? or do i have to clear the whole canvas and re-render it or something ?

**EDIT**
Have added a frame window to the canvas. Still scroll won't work. That could be the issue now ?

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("700x600")

frame_canvas = Frame(root)
frame_canvas.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame_canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

canvas = Canvas(frame_canvas, height=600, width=500)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

vsb = Scrollbar(frame_canvas, command=canvas.yview, orient="vertical")
vsb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

frame2 = Frame(canvas, bg="powder blue", height=600, width=700)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), anchor="nw", height=600, width=600, window=frame2)

for i in range(0, 50):
    for j in range(0, 4):
        frame2.columnconfigure(j, minsize=120)
        Label(frame2, bg="powder blue", text="hello"+str(i)+str(j)).grid(row=i, column=j)

canvas.config(scrollregion=frame2.bbox("all"))

app = root
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `Label` should go into a second `Frame`, `canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=frame2, anchor='nw')` and  `scrollregion=frame2.bbox()`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mentinon: Add `print(frame2.bbox())` before `.config(scrollregion=`, this will show the culprit. `.bbox()` returns `(0,0,0,0)` as the used size of a widget, here `frame` is unknown before the widget is displayed. Add `root.update()` to force to compute the bbox.